# Why does adding a space to text create different result on Windows vs. Mac?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have just made a game with Unity using text mesh pro for text rendering. There I add a first name and a last name together, like this:

```
text.text = Data.FirstName + ' ' + Data.LastName;
```

On windows this is working as expected:

[image]

But on mac it looks like this:

[image]

It seems that the last name gets returned to the start of the line and then pushed back by the space that I am adding.

Edit: I can produce the same result in windows if I instead of adding a space add "\r ". So a carriage return followed by a space.

Comment: As a non mac lover i would say it looks like its throwing returns instead of a space.

Comment: But a return would still show both lines. It is a \r and then a space. I can produce the same result in windows if I manually add a \r and a space.

Comment: What happens on mac if you use a constant `text.text = 'John Smith'`  and `text.text = 'John' + ' ' + 'Smith'` ?  That might tell you whether the issue is with your data or with the `+` operator

Comment: Where does the original text come from? If it's a text file generated on Windows it will have a CR/LF pair as a line ending instead of just LF that everyone else uses. Try opening it in Notepad++ and changing the line endings to LF only. You could also force git to do this or handle it in other ways. Using git to store and provide text files (including meta files) with linefeeds only has an added benefit to allowing you to generate asset bundles with the same hash on all platforms.

Comment: I would also suspect the issue being in the `Data` already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem was in the data itself.

I had a long list of names separated by \r\n. This I split up using Environment.NewLine. In windows this is \r\n but in macOS it is just \n.

I solved it by changing Environment.NewLine to "\r\n".